# Utilizar while para mostrar resultados de tres colunas

Tags: php

Desejo colocar as três colunas para mostrar seus resultados, tudo dentro de um mesmo WHILE, como devo fazer?

```
$movies = $db->query('SELECT * FROM movies AS M, highlights AS H, images AS I 
WHERE (M.movie_key = H.featured_key AND I.images_key = M.movie_key) AND (I.images_type = H.featured_type) AND H.featured_status = "ativo" 
ORDER BY H.featured_id DESC LIMIT 5');

$series = $db->query('SELECT * FROM series AS S, highlights AS H, images AS I 
WHERE (S.serie_key = H.featured_key AND I.images_key = S.serie_key) AND (I.images_type = H.featured_type) AND H.featured_status = "ativo" 
ORDER BY H.featured_id DESC LIMIT 5');

$animes = $db->query('SELECT * FROM animes AS A, highlights AS H, images AS I 
WHERE (A.anime_key = H.featured_key AND I.images_key = A.anime_key) AND (I.images_type = H.featured_type) AND H.featured_status = "ativo" 
ORDER BY H.featured_id DESC LIMIT 5');

if($movies->rowCount() != 0){
    while($database = $movies->fetch())
    {
        echo '<article class="item" id="post-'.$database['movie_key'].'">
            <div class="image">
                <a href="/assistir/filme/'.$database['movie_url'].'">
                    <img src="'.$database['images_slide'].'" alt="'.$database['movie_name'].'">
                </a>
                <a href="/assistir/filme/'.$database['movie_url'].'">
                    <div class="data">
                        <h3 class="title">'.$database['movie_name'].'</h3>
                        <span>'.$database['movie_year'].'</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <span class="item_type">FILME</span>
            </div>
        </article>';
    }
}

if($series->rowCount() != 0){
    while($database = $series->fetch())
    {
        echo '<article class="item" id="post-'.$database['serie_key'].'">
            <div class="image">
                <a href="/assistir/serie/'.$database['serie_url'].'">
                    <img src="'.$database['images_slide'].'" alt="'.$database['serie_name'].'">
                </a>
                <a href="/assistir/serie/'.$database['serie_url'].'">
                    <div class="data">
                        <h3 class="title">'.$database['serie_name'].'</h3>
                        <span>'.$database['serie_year'].'</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <span class="item_type">SÉRIE</span>
            </div>
        </article>';
    }
}

if($animes->rowCount() != 0){
    while($database = $animes->fetch())
    {
        echo '<article class="item" id="post-'.$database['anime_key'].'">
            <div class="image">
                <a href="/assistir/anime/'.$database['anime_url'].'">
                    <img src="'.$database['images_slide'].'" alt="'.$database['anime_name'].'">
                </a>
                <a href="/assistir/anime/'.$database['anime_url'].'">
                    <div class="data">
                        <h3 class="title">'.$database['anime_name'].'</h3>
                        <span>'.$database['anime_year'].'</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <span class="item_type">ANIME</span>
            </div>
        </article>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Não existe um relacionamento entre as tabelas  movies , series e animes ? Se existe porque está usando três consultas ao banco de dados se poderia montar apenas uma consulta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há algumas formas de fazer isso. O problema nesse caso parece ser de modelagem de dados.

> *Se possível poste a estrutura do seu banco de dados, assim poderemos analisar e recomendar uma determinada forma que seja melhor para seu problema.*

Uma das formas que vai servir é utilizando uma [função](http://br.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) para exibir os dados.

Para isso é necessário padronizar as informações capturadas com a `query`, para isso você **deverá** utilizar o [ALIAS](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp). Dessa forma você criará atalhos/apelidos seguindo um padrão que poderá ser utilizado na função.

```
$movies = $db->query('SELECT
    `movie_key` AS `key`,        /* Aqui eu informo que quero pegar o valor de "movie_key" e retornar em uma coluna chamada "key" */
    `movie_url` AS `url`,        /* Aqui eu informo que quero pegar o valor de "movie_url" e retornar em uma coluna chamada "url" */
    `images_slide` AS `slide`, 
    `movie_name` AS `name`, 
    `movie_year` AS `year`
FROM 
    movies AS M, 
    highlights AS H, 
    images AS I 
WHERE 
    (M.movie_key = H.featured_key AND I.images_key = M.movie_key) 
    AND (I.images_type = H.featured_type) 
    AND H.featured_status = "ativo" 
ORDER BY H.featured_id DESC 
LIMIT 5');
```

> *Siga esse padrão em todas as outras tabelas.*

---

Agora vamos definir a função que será responsável por exibir os dados.

```
function dislplayHtml($data, $type) {
    if($data->rowCount() != 0){
        while($database = $data->fetch())
        {
            //Gera a URL
            $url = sprintf('/assistir/%s/%s',

                //Traduz caracteres especiais como áéíóú
                strtolower(preg_replace("/\W/", "", iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $type))),

                //Concatena a URL
                $database['url']);

            echo '<article class="item" id="post-'.$database['key'].'">
                <div class="image">
                    <a href="'.$url.'">
                        <img src="'.$database['slide'].'" alt="'.$database['name'].'">
                    </a>
                    <a href="'.$url.'">
                        <div class="data">
                            <h3 class="title">'.$database['name'].'</h3>
                            <span>'.$database['year'].'</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <span class="item_type">'.strtoupper($type).'</span>
                </div>
            </article>';
        }
    }
}
```

Observe que não utilizei o nome das colunas "movie_key", "serie_key" etc. Utilizei apenas o `alias` que criei com a `query` anterior e por isso o padrão é tão importante.

Para exibir basta chamar a função `displayHtml`. Nessa função é necessário passar como parâmetro o resultado de `$db->query` e o *"tipo"*. Ex:

```
dislplayHtml($movies, "Filmes");
dislplayHtml($movies, "Séries");
dislplayHtml($movies, "Anime");
```

Comment: vou testar querido, se der certo, classifico.

Comment: testei o script, porém deu na mesma de como eu tinha feito antes, só que mais organizado, gostei em si, preciso de sua ajuda em outro detalhe agora dentro desse script, se você puder me adicionar skype, fico agradecido: lenux.games